# data.table shift() doesn't seem to "lead" correctly

Tags: r, data.table

I'm a beginner to data.table.  Can anyone explain to me why I cant get the expected result with `shift()`? (I get the same result with "lead" or "lag")

```
set.seed(123)
x <- data.table(a = sample(1:10,10,replace = F))
x <- x[order(a)][, a1 := shift(a,1,"lead")]
x
     a a1
 1:  1 NA
 2:  2  1
 3:  3  2
 4:  4  3
 5:  5  4
 6:  6  5
 7:  7  6
 8:  8  7
 9:  9  8
10: 10  9
```

Here is the result I am expecting:

```
data.table(a = 1:10, a1 = c(2:10,NA))
     a a1
 1:  1  2
 2:  2  3
 3:  3  4
 4:  4  5
 5:  5  6
 6:  6  7
 7:  7  8
 8:  8  9
 9:  9 10
10: 10 NA
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function definition for `shift` is

```
shift(x, n=1L, fill=NA, type=c("lag", "lead"), give.names=FALSE)
```

However, as you haven't specified the arguments you're using, the function assumes your third one is being used for the `fill` argument (the third one in the definition).

So what you're actually doing is

```
shift(x = a, n = 1, fill = "lead", type = "lag", give.names = FALSE) 
## where type & give.names are using their default values
```

You probably want to explicitly state the arguments:

```
set.seed(123)
library(data.table)
x <- data.table(a = sample(1:10,10,replace = F))


x[order(a)][, a1 := shift(a, n = 1, type = "lead")][]
#      a a1
# 1:  1  2
# 2:  2  3
# 3:  3  4
# 4:  4  5
# 5:  5  6
# 6:  6  7
# 7:  7  8
# 8:  8  9
# 9:  9 10
# 10: 10 NA
```